# How do I scale a PDF page while maintaining orientation with iTextSharp?

Tags: itext

How do I scale a pdf page, while maintaining rotation in itextsharp?
I have the following, but I lose rotation:

```
    public static void ScaleToLetter(string inPDF, string outPDF)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inPDF);
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        Document.Compress = true;
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, 
            new FileStream(outPDF, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        int rotation;

        PdfImportedPage page;
        for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageNumber++)
        {
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
            rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(pageNumber);

            cb.AddTemplate(page, 
                PageSize.LETTER.Width / reader.GetPageSize(pageNumber).Width, 
                0, 0, 
                PageSize.LETTER.Height / reader.GetPageSize(pageNumber).Height, 
                0, 0);
            doc.NewPage();
        }
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar issue, and got it working by changing the height and width of each page, from LETTER to LETTER rotated. In other words, if the current page is thin and tall then it is vertical. But if it is wide and short, then it is horizontal and I should rotate the page.

Here's your code changed:

```
    public static void ScaleToLetter(string inPDF, string outPDF)
    {
        using (var reader           = new PdfReader(inPDF))
        using (var doc              = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
        {
            Document.Compress       = true;
            using (
                var writer          = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc,
                    new FileStream(outPDF, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                doc.Open();
                var cb              = writer.DirectContent;

                PdfImportedPage page;
                for (var pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageNumber++)
                {
                    page            = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);

                    if (page.Width <= page.Height)
                        doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
                    else
                        doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());
                    doc.NewPage();

                    cb.AddTemplate(page,
                        doc.PageSize.Width / reader.GetPageSize(pageNumber).Width,
                        0, 0,
                        doc.PageSize.Height / reader.GetPageSize(pageNumber).Height,
                        0, 0);
                }
                doc.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also needed to constrain proportions, so I ended up with this:

```
 public static void ScaleToA4(string inPDF, string outPDF)
    {
        using (var reader        = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(inPDF))))
        using (var document      = new Document(PageSize.A4))
        using (var ms            = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer        = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms))
        {
            document.Open();
            var cb               = writer.DirectContent;

            for (var pageNumber  = 1; pageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageNumber++)
            {
                var page         = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
                document.SetPageSize(page.Width <= page.Height ?
                    PageSize.A4 : PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                document.NewPage();

                var widthFactor  = document.PageSize.Width / page.Width;
                var heightFactor = document.PageSize.Height / page.Height;
                var factor       = Math.Min(widthFactor, heightFactor);

                var offsetX      = (document.PageSize.Width - (page.Width * factor)) / 2;
                var offsetY      = (document.PageSize.Height - (page.Height * factor)) / 2;
                cb.AddTemplate(page, factor, 0, 0, factor, offsetX, offsetY);
            }
            document.Close();
            File.WriteAllBytes(outPDF, ms.GetBuffer());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using this solution has worked very well for me, except for if the PDF has an electronic signature, in which circumstance the electronic signature doesn't make it into the resized page. Any idea how to resize including the electronic signature?