# Copy page content from a large pdf page to smaller pdf page

Tags: itext

I have a PDF file that is 22*17 and I am needing it to fit that page content in a 11*8.5 page.

Basically reducing existing page size. I am using iTextSharp.

How do I do it?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606826/how-do-i-scale-a-pdf-page-while-maintaining-orientation-with-itextsharp

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device for this instead of itextsharp. Something like:

```
gs \
 -sDEVICEHIGHTPOINTS=612 -sDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=792 \
 -dFIXEDMEDIA \
 -dPDFFitPage \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
  input.pdf
```

caveat: This will fully interpret the PDF file to marking operations and emit a brand new PDF (rescaled to fit the new media size), depending on the content of the file you may or may not like the result.

Comment: Thank you much for the answer. I already found a solution from the link ColinPickard posted. however I will try the one you provided in later time.